# Copy the cell value to another cell if

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing VBA in Excel and I have a cell with some numbers in it and I have a "shopping cart" range and I when I click on the button I want to copy the cell value to the "cart" but if the first row in the cart is already full it should move on the next row and do this until it finds a row that it empty and paste it in there.

I tried to do it but got a problem

```
Sub Gumb1_Klikni()

  Range("B1").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("J2").Select
  If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
  Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
  Else
  Set nextcell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
  Range(nextcell).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  End If

End Sub
```

It gives me Error 1004 "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" at

```
Range(nextcell).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would define `Dim nextcell as Range` at the beginning of your `Sub` , all you need to do is:

```
nextcell.Select
```

However, you could use the "Cleaner" version below, without the need to use `Select` or `Selection` :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Gumb1_Klikni()

Dim nextCell As Range

Range("B1").Copy
If IsEmpty(Range("J2")) Then
    Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Else
    Set nextCell = Range("J2").Offset(1, 0)
    nextCell.PasteSpecial
End If

End Sub
```

**Edit 1:** after PO clarification:

```
Sub Gumb1_Klikni()

Dim LastRow As Long

' get last row with data in column "J"
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow < 1 Then LastRow = 1

Range("B1").Copy
Range("J" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Comment: It works but just for 2 times. 1st time it paste in the cell J2, 2nd time it pastes in the next row but then clicks on the button don't do anything and it leaves B1 copied.

Comment: @Venoox  what do you want to happen on 2nd, 3rd and so on tries ? Where do you want to paste ? At the first empty row at column J ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: OK - I'll ask a stupid question - How can `Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row` return a number `< 1`?  I didn't think Excel allowed row 0 (or negative, or fractional)!

Comment: @YowE3K good question, I think at night time when I'm tired it could ;)